# Button failure [HTML-PHP-CSS]

Tags: php, html, css

An online / offline button down on the original code, I want to make changes through the code, but I failed

```
<li class="li-icon"><a href="#"><i class="label<?php $UserData->invisible_mode == 1 ? print ' offline-mode-label' : ' online-mode-label'?>" onclick="return lhinst.changeVisibility($(this))"></i></a></li>
```

but, I changed the code:

```
<span class="label<?php $UserData->invisible_mode == 1 ? print ' offline-mode-label' : ' online-mode-label'?>" onclick="return lhinst.disableUserAsOnline($(this))"><a href="#"><?php
$UserData->hide_online == 1 ? print 'Offline Mode' :
'Online Mode'?></a></span>
```

But don't work button on the screen. Errors where?

Comment: `<?php print (($UserData->hide_online == 1) ? 'Offline Mode' : 'Online Mode'); ?>`
I think this is what you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
    <span class="label<?php print (($UserData->invisible_mode == 1) ? ' offline-mode-label' : ' online-mode-label'); ?>" onclick="return lhinst.disableUserAsOnline($(this))">
        <a href="#">
            <?php print (($UserData->hide_online == 1) ? print 'Offline Mode' : 'Online Mode'); ?>
        </a>
    </span>
```

You are missing semi colons and you can move the print to outside conditional check

Or maybe you can move the conditional checks outside and assign the results to variables, cleans the code a bit and helps you debug :)

```
    <?php 
    $className = 'label'.(($UserData->invisible_mode == 1) ? ' offline-mode-label' : ' online-mode-label'); 
    $label = (($UserData->hide_online == 1) ? 'Offline Mode' : 'Online Mode');
    ?>
    <span class="<?php print  $className; ?>" onclick="return lhinst.disableUserAsOnline($(this))">
        <a href="#">
            <?php print $label; ?>
        </a>
    </span>
```

Comment: Yes working! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try putting your php code outside the class attribute...like this...

```
    <li class="li-icon"><a href="#"><i class="label" onclick="return lhinst.changeVisibility($(this))"  <?php $UserData->invisible_mode == 1 ? print ' offline-mode-label' : ' online-mode-label'?>></i></a></li>
```